# How can I add interpreter to PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

When I try to run code in editor,it says that there is no available interpreters.Please,help.How can I solve the problem?

Comment: This now is in all new projects, so it offers the virtualenv interpreter and locates installed Python(windows) as base interpreter

Answer (score 17):

Just read the PyCharm's Docs.

https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/configuring_interpreter.html

Step by step:

1. Go to `Settings`.
2. Go to the section `Project Interpreter` .
3. Click on the plus *(+)* button and select the `Local` option.
4. Search for the interpreter, in Linux it is used to be in `/usr/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/pythonX.Y` where X and Y are the version. In Windows, it is used to be in `C:\python`.
5. Last step save the settings and you have configured the interpreter.

PD: If you are on Linux python is installed and if you are using Windows, you can download from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: (What if there is no Preferences section called Project?)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to run this command

$ sudo apt-get install python3-distutils

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do to setting you can just use the drop-down to the left of the run arrow in the top menu [image]

Answer (score -1):

This page [Configuring Python Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) tells all the information you need.

To configure Python virtual environment, follow these steps:

1. In the Settings/Preferences dialog (⌘,), click Project Interpreter.
2. Click gear icon and choose Add ....
   [image]
3. In the left-hand pane of this dialog, click the Virtual Environment node.
4. Click OK to apply changes and close the dialog box.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to File.
2. Settings
3. Then you receive another window. Find line which is called project name.
4. Expand and it Click interpeter.
5. Then click the wheel icon which is next to the interpreter.
6. Click add button.
7. Then it gives a new window. Then we can create a new environment or add exiting environment.

Choos is yours.....