# Setting up existing Python3.6 environment/packages in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed `pycharm community 2019.2.4` version and `python 3.6` independently. 
My existing python has all the required packages installed.

Now whenever I open `new project`in Pycharm, every-time it creates a `new virtual environment` with no packages pre-installed. So every time I have to install packages.

I also tried to change interpreter with existing python location, but it didn't worked. Here are the steps I followed:

My `python3.6` location: `C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`

```
      1. Open Pycharm -> Go to configure -> Settings
      2. Project Interpreter -> Add -> 
      3. In the Add section I add the new location as `C:\Users\user-name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`


      4. Then I click on New-Project and then ok.
```

I see new virtual environment created.

If someone can help me with some documents of steps that would be very helpful. I followed some previous links in stackoverflow but may be I am missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add interpreter to PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768371/how-can-i-add-interpreter-to-pycharm)

Comment: Pycharm doesn't use the installed version of python it actually uses it's own virtual python environment to run your projects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 'add' section you should be available to select the checkbox "use existing environment". There you should pass a path to your system python executable. The same thing should be available during project creation.

P.s. Could you provide us screenshots of changing the interpreter window and 'Add' section.

Comment: Hey, Thanks I got it, It was not in add section. But it was on window of New Project creation. Just a small icon and it was showing 2 options... existing environment or virtual.