# Failed To Create Interpreter Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

when i create a new project in pycharm i get the following error
[image]
what happened and how to solve it?

I've tried reinstalling python (for all users and not all users)
I installed python 3.9.5 but i have also installed python 3.8.6

this my path
[image]

Comment: You should edit the question to include a screenshot from the dialogue before you press the button to try and create the new interpreter. What is currently causing the error is that PyCharm is trying to execute Python from `C:\users\...\ProgramTools\venv\...` as shown in the 1st screenshot, but that is not where your Python base installation is located. For some reason you probably have PyCharm configured to use an old venv as interpreter that was at that location.

Comment: To solve this try setting the Python base interpreter [in the project settings like this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#view_list) and point it to the executable in your fresh Python installation at `C:\Program Files\Python3.9\python.exe`. After that is done you should be able to create a venv from that base interpreter which is what your last 2 screenshots are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pip is updated or not.
Use command 'python -m pip install –upgrade pip' to upgrade pip
And if you are new just use only one python version.

Comment: it shows error like this https://imgur.com/a/t3CDwQr

Answer (score 0):

To update `pip` on pycharm:

Open project settings (File > Settings...) (preferences on Mac)

Project > Project Interpreter.

Press the `+` button.

Type `"pip"` in the top search box.

In the lower right corner choose "specify version"

Choose your version(`latest version`) and press Install Package.

Comment: it shows like this , i can't click the + button.
https://imgur.com/a/2c2BOyl

Comment: you go this file-->setting-->python interpreter-->choice your python version : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768371/how-can-i-add-interpreter-to-pycharm

Comment: it shows i only can use python 3.8, while 3.9 shows like this https://imgur.com/a/AKtdV3M

Comment: when you make new project you choice `Base interpreter` like this https://imgur.com/a/X24fqXh Therefore, the desired version of Python must be installed on your system for Virtualenv

Comment: Change to the path where you installed Python : https://imgur.com/a/jGZNdNH