# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I installed the keyboard library but when I use it I get that it is not installed, I don't know if I have to add something.

`import keyboard`

I get this in the Windows console to check if it is installed.

```
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in c:\users\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (0.13.5)
```

I tried many ways but no function.

Comment: So it works in the console but not in PyCharm?  Is that it?  PyCharm probably has its own installation of Python.  You need to install `keyboard` there.

Comment: "I get that it is not installed". You have obviously a problem with your environment, you should post the exception itself instead of interpreting it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add interpreter to PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768371/how-can-i-add-interpreter-to-pycharm)